# maya 2020 cannot show dds texture

Tags: maya, dds-format

I'm trying to import dds texture in maya 2020, but it cannot work. Everything is well in maya2018 one year ago.
[the image even not show in the preview, it seems that maya cannot read the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pscU3.png)
I'm quite sure that the dds file has no problem because it works well in other platform. Other formats of images can work, only dds has such problem.

I have changed the viewport 2.0 render engine to directx 11, but it still not work.